# Configuring Java build path for External Libraries adding jars into Reference Library

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, buildpath

I am using **MAC** with **Eclipse Juno**. My problem is When I create **Dynamic Web Project** in Eclipse and configure **Java Build Path**, all the external jars are getting added in the **Referenced Library**, rather than **web-inf >> lib**. So each time while running the project I have to manually copy-paste the jar to web-inf >> lib. Please let me know if i have to make any change in eclipse for this. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to also export the libraries.

Project properties -> Java Build path. You'll see something similar to the screen shot.

[image: Dialog to select dependencies]

Just check which library you want to export. It will be copied to `lib` folder